# Qt - QTableView - Clickable button in table row

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qitemdelegate

I require a button/link within a table row of a `QTableView`. This is to open a dialog to allow that row to be edited more efficiently.

After hours of looking on the web I am yet to find a decent example.

I am aware that this is likely to be done using a `QItemDelegate`, but I am unsure how to have a functional widget within the row without forcing the item into edit mode first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Button in table row"? Whole row? Or in a single cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could emulate the functionality of a link by underlining the clickable text, then capturing the cell click via the cellClicked(row, col) signal and check that col == editColumn. Then row would correspond to which item you are editing.

For example,

Data Name | Value 1 | Value 2 | *Edit*

```
connect (tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int,int)), this, SLOT(editSlot(int, int)));

...

void ClassName::editSlot(int row, int col){
  if (col == 3) {
    doWork(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does the accepted answer invariably fail to actually answer the question? Defining a new signal-slot connection merely to add a single static button or link to a table item at table definition time is nonsensical. Honestly, StackOverflow should just default to dynamically marking the answer currently receiving the most upvotes as "accepted."

Answer (score 25):

You can use `setIndexWidget` for that, see the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) for more information.

As an example, to embed a push button in the first column of the second row (untested code):

```
tableView->setIndexWidget(tableView->model()->index(2, 1), new QPushButton);
```

Comment: I have read that on large datasets, setting a row level widget can incur a noticeable performance loss.