# How to display drop-down in column of QTableView and filter based on drop-down

Tags: qt

I am newbie to Qt.  I have to display a chunk of data in a `QTableView` and filter it column wise. For this I have used `QSortFilterProxyModel`, but as per requirement each column of the `QTableView` should have a drop-down list which shows unique values in that column. On selection of any of these values in the drop-down, only the rows having that particular value in the column should be displayed in the `QTableView` (Like you can do in Excel).

How would I implement this?

Comment: Although it's for a spinbox, not a combo-box, the standard Qt example [spinboxdelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html) shows how to create a `QItemDelegate` subclass to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very general question, and if I try to explain it all it will take pages, so it's better if you read the Qt [model/view architecture documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html).

You can create your own class inherited from [`QTableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html) to create your customized table view.  You have to use delegates for drop down functions and all. so read the [`QItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) class documentation and [documentation on subclassing delegates](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes) as well.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue a week ago
I found a tutorial explaining how to do it. see link below
http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/Delegates/ComboBoxDelegate

Now my problem is how to retrieve the value of a specific combobox.
I think it is such a complex things to do in C++ and Qt display a combobox into a tableView.
For being a web developer at first I can tell that web language are better suited to do thoses kind of things.

But still some time performance matter and I tried to do it in C++ with Qt but it is not as easy as it seems to be in Web language.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display it always and not just when editing, I would suggest setting a widget for the specific column like described in this thread: [Qt - QTableView - Clickable button in table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412796/qt-qtableview-clickable-button-in-table-row)