# HowTo create model/view QTableView with custom (non-editable) delegates?

Tags: qt, delegates, qt4, qtableview

Here is what I'm trying to get ( this is a `QTableView` widget + *MVC* based on `QAbstractTableModel` with multiply *delegates* ):

[image]

**Notes:**

- Delegates a not working as editors, they are ONLY viewers! I'm not getting to edit model with this table view.
- Delegates must be realizable. It means that all total height of the BLUE row could be 25px, or 250px.
- MV is simple data:

  1ROW: CompanyName1  Name1,Name2,Name3   OTHER DATA

  2ROW: CompanyName2  SingleName1         OTHER DATA

  3ROW: CompanyName3  Name1,Name2         OTHER DATA and so on...

**Question:**

- Is it possible to create custom delegate (`QItemDelegate`, or `QStyleItemDelegate`), for example, to the 2nd column like on the image above? And if it's possible, maybe you could give me some examples, or resource links where can I look at them.

---

PS. Yes, I have looked at all *Qt Demo* examples with delegates, but I just don't get it, how to do what I want.

PSS. `QTableView` -> `setIndexWidget()` I think that is not a good idea. But `QTableView` ->`setItemDelegateForColumn( myCustomDelegate )` methods are better!

P3S. I'm not looking solution for `QTableWidget` class...

Thank you for your replies! :-)

---

**Update #1:**

- I think that:

  - Delegates are used only for edits (for example, if we are working with model/view object) and manage similar items (all/just column/just row).
  - Custom widgets are better, but I have not meet them in free Qt projects. And it's not too easy to get the nice and correct code of such kind of widgets...

---

**Addition:**

- Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412796/qt-qtableview-clickable-button-in-table-row) to similarity question.

Comment: Can you describe how you fetch the data from your model? Are you using custom Roles? For example, how would I get 'CompanyName2' for a particular row?

Comment: For now, I don't have such a solution. Only `QTreeWidget` + my custom widgets. In my Question I'm looking for an answer which will contain the information about joining thing like: table view, models and delegates all together...

Comment: @mosg it would be a lot easier to answer if you included a full minimal working example in which you want to do X.  Frankly, I found the spinbox delegate example very helpful and simple. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html. I work in python, so can't help too much with specifics, other than the answer below: it is actually pretty easy--just reimplement paint for a read-only model. The rest of the work goes back to the delegate base class.

Comment: @neuronet Thanks for the reply, but I don't need the answer any more, because it was long-long-long time ago... Truely sad, this UI prototype was terrible, and soon we refused this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are not only useful for creating widgets used in editing. They are also used in creating the overall look and feel of each visible index (in this case, a table cell).

You can custom create the look and feel by reimplementing the [paint()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qstyleditemdelegate.html#id-d1ab427a-2075-41ce-861a-b62507c586c1) method of the delegate.